# How to run basic hello world app using electron framework , node.js on windows platform

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I have created the package.json, main.js and index.html files, stored them all in the folder, but when I try to run the application the following errors are displayed.[image: Errors]

Comment: Could you post the package.json?

Comment: {
  "name"    : "arun_electron",
  "version" : "0.1.0",
  "main"    : "main.js"
}

Comment: That's why, you don't have the `start` under `scripts` in the `package.json`

Comment: Piero , can u help me in resolving the issue

Comment: Did you try one of the answers below?

Answer (score 0):

There could be two solutions if you want to use `npm start` (fixing either them should be enough):

1. No start script in package.json
2. No server.js file

**Number 1 solution:**
Do you have a `start` script in your `package.json` file? - as it looks like you may be missing it.

To fix this, go into your project directory, and open up your `package.json` file, and add the following script (replacing *your-fil*e with your actual file name):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node your-file.js"
}
```

**Number 2 solution:**
Change your application name (e.g. myapp.js) to `server.js`, and try running npm start again.

**OR SIMPLY...** just run the `node myapp.js` (replacing myapp.js with your actual file name that you want to run) command rather than `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your package.json with this one

```
{
  "name" : "arun_electron", 
  "version" : "0.1.0", 
  "main" : "main.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^0.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron main.js"
  }
}
```

when you run `npm start`, the command `electron main.js` will be executed.

Comment: Dear Yudu , I made the possible changes as suggested by you but still I am getting the error "electron is not recognized as an internal and external command"

Comment: @ArunAgarwal you should run `npm install` after change, to install electron(the devDependencies section in package.json).

Comment: @ArunAgarwal Also be sure to add './node_modules/.bin' to your PATH.  Add the line `export PATH=$PATH:./node_modules/.bin` to your `.bashrc` or `.profile` in home directory.